# i can't run rake db:create on mountain lion

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, osx-mountain-lion

I have updated my OSX to mountain lion and my mysql too.. so now i can't run any db rake command...

```
diego@diego-imac vanilla (work) $ rake db:create

(in /Users/diego/Documents/v2v/projects/vanilla)
Couldn't create database for {"encoding"=>"utf8", "username"=>"root", "adapter"=>"mysql", "database"=>"v2v_vanilla_dev", "password"=>nil}, charset: utf8, collation: utf8_unicode_ci (if you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
```

I found many solution on web, but none solved my problem.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks

some informations:

> Server version: 5.1.60 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

```
mysql (2.8.1)
    Author: TOMITA Masahiro
    Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/mysql-win
    Homepage: http://mysql-win.rubyforge.org
    Installed at: /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@v2v

    This is the MySQL API module for Ruby
```

> rails (2.3.11)
>
> diego@diego-imac vanilla (work) $ which mysql
>   /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql

```
diego@diego-imac local (master) $ ls -lha | grep mysql 

lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel    24B 26 Jul 15:31 mysql -> mysql-5.1.60-osx10.6-x86
drwxr-xr-x  16 root   wheel   544B 29 Out  2011 mysql-5.1.60-osx10.6-x86
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure after the update MySql is still running: click to System Preferences -> Other -> MySql or just run in the terminal:

```
ps ax|grep mysqld|grep -v grep
```

(the output shouldn't be empty).

Run it if necessary (with Start button in Preferences or `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe` in terminal).